# Proof that linear returns aggregate across securities

Tags: returns, optimization

I keep reading that linear returns aggregate across securities, but I'm having trouble proving it. I suspect there's some mistake in my approach; I'd appreciate some help in seeing it.

Suppose we have two securities, $A$ and $B$. They have prices at timestep $t$ of $P_A^t$ and $P_B^t$, respectively. The portfolio has weights $w_A$ and $w_B$, which sum to 1. The price of the portfolio is then

$$P_P^t = w_A P_A^t + w_B P_B^t.$$

We define linear returns via the formula

$$R^t = \frac{P^t}{P^{t-1}} - 1.$$

Thus, the linear returns of the portfolio are

$$R_P^t = \frac{P_P^t}{P_P^{t-1}} - 1 = \frac{w_A P_A^t + w_B P_B^t}{w_A P_A^{t-1} + w_B P_B^{t-1}} - 1$$

I see it claimed in [various locations](http://www.portfolioprobe.com/2010/10/04/a-tale-of-two-returns/) [around the internet](https://poseidon01.ssrn.com/delivery.php?ID=237074081092012096086001116016087117052050089038069021127118099117101114098094011105100061021123008121098000026097009087086095011010071043048118000071025127088011089034030071127117006111112020122118087104086106075113082116076080016090065079127117000&EXT=pdf) that these returns aggregate over securities, which is to say that

$$R_P^t = w_A R_A^t + w_B R_B^t.$$

However, this formula yields

$$ R_P^t = w_A \frac{P_A^t}{P_A^{t-1}} + w_B \frac{P_B^t}{P_B^{t-1}} - 1$$

which, as far as I can see, is not in general equal to the previous expression for returns. In particular,

$$ w_A \frac{P_A^t}{P_A^{t-1}} + w_B \frac{P_B^t}{P_B^{t-1}} \neq \frac{w_A P_A^t + w_B P_B^t}{w_A P_A^{t-1} + w_B P_B^{t-1}}.$$

What am I missing here? I need to be able to use linearity when justifying Markowitz-style optimization.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are simply confusing percentage weights and number of assets.

In your definition the **initial percentage weight** of the $m$ assets in the portfolio are given by $w_i^{t - 1}$ and they sum to one, i.e.

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i = 1}^m w_i^{t - 1} = 1.
\end{equation}

Now define the **absolute number of assets** as $n_i$. They are linked to the percentage weights through

\begin{equation}
w_i^{t - 1} = \frac{n_i P_i^{t - 1}}{\sum_{j = 1}^m n_j P_j^{t - 1}}.
\end{equation}

As you don't rebalance your portfolio, the number of assets stays the same in $t - 1$ and $t$. The value of the portfolio at any time $t$ is

\begin{equation}
P_P^t = \sum_{i = 1}^m n_i P_i^t.
\end{equation}

Then

\begin{eqnarray}
R_P^t & = & \frac{P_P^t}{P_P^{t - 1}} - 1\\
& = & \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^m n_i P_i^t}{\sum_{j = 1}^m n_j P_j^{t - 1}} - 1\\
& = & \sum_{i = 1}^m \left( \frac{n_i P_i^{t - 1}}{\sum_{j = 1}^m n_j P_j^{t - 1}} \right)\frac{P_i^t}{P_i^{t - 1}} - 1\\
& = & \sum_{i = 1}^m w_i^{t - 1} \frac{P_i^t}{P_i^{t - 1}} - 1\\
& = & \sum_{i = 1}^m w_i^{t - 1} R_i^t
\end{eqnarray}

Note that generally $w_i^t \neq w_i^{t - 1}$.

Comment: In simple terms the $n_i$ would be for example the number of shares of stock, e.g. you have 100 shares of MSFT and 200 shares of XOM... or whatever.

Comment: This is helpful. Another way that I have thought about it is that rather than using price $P_t$, I use a scaled value $V_t$ where $V_0=1$ by definition.